# Issue blocking a user's account to send email through Postfix

Tags: postfix

When trying to block outgoing emails for a specific user both locally and outside I entered the Postfix configuration in main.cf `SMTPD_Recipient_Restrictions = Check_sender_access hash: /etc/postfix/sender_access` with this text `user@mydomain.com Reject` then `Postmap Sender_access` for create the .db file.

Via webmail and with mail clients such as Thunderbird or Outlook everything is ok.  Sending is locked either using port 25 and 465 ssl/tls but if the clients use port 587 with STARTTLs sending succeeds.

How to stop sending also via port 587 with mail clients?

**postconf -n**

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
authorized_flush_users =
authorized_mailq_users =
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 5
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 10240000
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = mydomain.my
mynetworks =
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-3.5.9/README_FILES
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient,header_recipient
recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:12346
recipient_delimiter = +
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-3.5.9/samples
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_bind_address = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /usr/local/psa/etc/dhparams2048.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtputf8_enable = no
tls_medium_cipherlist = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/certs
transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_gid_maps = static:30
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
```

**postconf-M**

```
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
postlog    unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
plesk_virtual unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DORhu user=popuser:popuser argv=/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/postfix-local -f ${sender} -d ${recipient} -p /var/qmail/mailnames -q ${queue_id}
127.0.0.1:12346 inet n   n       n       -       -       spawn user=popuser:popuser argv=/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/postfix-srs
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=R user=mailman:mailman argv=/usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/postfix-mailman ${nexthop} ${user} ${recipient}
pickup     fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
qmgr       fifo  n       -       n       1       1       qmgr
smtps      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
plesk_saslauthd unix y   y       n       -       1       plesk_saslauthd status=5 listen=6 dbpath=/var/spool/postfix/plesk/passwd.db
```

Plesk Obsidian 18.0.40.1 OS version: CentOS 7.9.2009 x86_64

Answer (score 1):

[`check_sender_access`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_sender_access) belongs in `smtpd_sender_restrictions`, not in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

Comment: I tried the change you suggested but it's the same with the port 587 so I saw that in master.cf there is this line `-o smtpd_sender_restrictions =` empty and I tried to comment with # and maybe I found the solution because now the user is also blocked on port 587 but don't know if this change can make other issue...

Answer (score 1):

You are offering submission services on two ports, with different option overrides:

1. legacy STARTTLS on port 587 (`submission` in first column in `master.cf`)
2. SMTP wrapped in TLS on port 465 (`smtps` in first column in `master.cf`)

You currently do not require auth on both those ports, yet override restrictions for only one:

```
smtps      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
 -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
 -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
```

What I expect what you want is something like this: requiring auth on both ports, and only overriding sender and client restrictions, while still applying global recipient restrictions:

```
smtps      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
 -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
submission inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
 -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
```

If not overridden, your recipient restrictions from the `main.cf` file would then apply to both those services.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

(unrelated: you may not want to allow authentication on port 25 - you are allowing connections without transport security there. When you override it for all (2) submission ports anyway, reconsider `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes` in `main.cf`)